# reduce delay in display progress bar

Tags: android, delay, progressdialog

As I created a Progress bar using below code in a on click method of button. but after clicking button it takes 2-3 seconds to display progress bar.how to reduce that delay to start progress bar.

```
 public void getProgressBar() {

    progressBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressBar.setCancelable(true);
    progressBar.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressBar.show();
    progressBarStatus = 0;

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (progressBarStatus < 100) {

                progressBarStatus = doSomeTasks();////I am loading service 
                progressBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        progressBar.setProgress(progressBarStatus);
                    }
                });
            }

                if (progressBarStatus >= 100 ) {

                    progressBar.dismiss();
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            StatisticDisplay.class));

            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public class BackgroundAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

  int myProgress;

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   myProgress = 0;
  }

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   while(myProgress<100){
    myProgress++;
    publishProgress(myProgress);
       SystemClock.sleep(100);
   }
   return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: @Kedar That's not my fault.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead. The example code in the link gives a good introduction on how to do it. In essence you do the job in doInBackground(), publish your progress using onProgressUpdate() and start your activiy in onPostExecute().

Comment: but problem here is I tried just to display progress bar on clicking a button I want to show progress bar but its displaying after 2-3 sec.I tried a dummy progress bar its not doing any action even it is taking delay.